# Durable Function Fan out limitations in Azure

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

Is there a way that I can choose the amount of fans in my durable function?

I would like to make a quick demonstration where my function fans out 5 times the first run, 10 the second, and 50 the third to demonstrate the advantage of fanning out.

How do I set a limit on how much the function is able to fan out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the azure portal under the "Scaling" tab, you can limit the number of fans.